# How to get activity name on exception using logcat?

Tags: android, adb

Any solution or Hint for finding activity name in which error or exception occurred from LogCat.

your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Log cat exception usually shows the cause of exception, line number and the name of java class as well :) Can you post your log cat

Comment: Yes true log cat shows class name in logcat :)

Comment: Are you asking about what to do if you catch and exception and want to log the activity where it happened?

Comment: Yes ,Sandeep and Jhaman logcat shows the java class name , but i want to get exact current activity name in which exception occurred.

Comment: Doug Steven, actually i want get the activity name in which exception occurred by using adb. when ever my app got crash then i would be able to get that activity name in which error occurred .

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable:

```
private static final String TAG = YourActivity.class.getSimpleName();
```

and then use this code to get LogCat message:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Message " + ex.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Log.d(TAG, "...Any Thing... ");
```

put TAG as `public static String TAG = "Your Activity name";`on your activity

Comment: Thanks Basi for giving answer, But i want to get this by using adb logact command and using filtering on it.